# Postgres two similar queries, one using the correct index, one not

Tags: postgresql, indexing, sql-execution-plan

I have two tables, `subjects` and `answers`. The `subjects` table looks like this:

```
  Column   |         Type          |  
-----------+-----------------------+
 id        | integer               | 
 survey_id | character varying(36) |
Indexes:
    "subjects_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "ix_subjects_survey_id" btree (survey_id)
```

The `answers` table looks like this:

```
         Column         |            Type             |       
------------------------+-----------------------------+
 id                     | integer                     | 
 subject_id             | integer                     |
 answer                 | character varying(4096)     | 
Indexes:
    "answers_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "ix_answers_subject_id" btree (subject_id)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "answers_subject_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (subject_id) REFERENCES subjects(id)
```

The answers table is very large, over 800 million rows. Everything seems appropriately indexed, with the correct FK relationships. I am trying to get all of the answers for all subjects who have a particular `survey_id`, but the indices aren't being used unless I tweak the query. The base query that I would expect to work:

```
  EXPLAIN SELECT a.subject_id, a.answer
  FROM wp_fieldwork.answers a
  INNER JOIN wp_fieldwork.subjects s ON a.subject_id = s.id
  WHERE s.survey_id = '6be229a0-f497-4d19-a76c-f11361f9573b'
  ORDER BY a.subject_id 
                                                          QUERY PLAN                                                          
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Gather Merge  (cost=9450784.26..9561177.54 rows=946162 width=13)
   Workers Planned: 2
   ->  Sort  (cost=9449784.24..9450966.94 rows=473081 width=13)
         Sort Key: a.subject_id
         ->  Parallel Hash Join  (cost=10775.66..9397107.27 rows=473081 width=13)
               Hash Cond: (a.subject_id = s.id)
               ->  Parallel Seq Scan on answers a  (cost=0.00..8708933.87 rows=258055787 width=13)
               ->  Parallel Hash  (cost=10754.52..10754.52 rows=1691 width=4)
                     ->  Parallel Bitmap Heap Scan on subjects s  (cost=212.01..10754.52 rows=1691 width=4)
                           Recheck Cond: ((survey_id)::text = '6be229a0-f497-4d19-a76c-f11361f9573b'::text)
                           ->  Bitmap Index Scan on ix_subjects_survey_id  (cost=0.00..211.00 rows=4059 width=0)
                                 Index Cond: ((survey_id)::text = '6be229a0-f497-4d19-a76c-f11361f9573b'::text)
```

As you can see, it's doing a full table scan, rather than using the `ix_answers_subject_id` index on the `answers` table. But here's what happens when I limit the bounds of the `subject_id`:

```
  EXPLAIN SELECT a.subject_id, a.answer
  FROM answers a
  INNER JOIN subjects s ON a.subject_id = s.id
  WHERE s.survey_id = '6be229a0-f497-4d19-a76c-f11361f9573b'
  AND a.subject_id <= (SELECT MAX(id) FROM subjects WHERE survey_id = '6be229a0-f497-4d19-a76c-f11361f9573b')
  AND a.subject_id >= (SELECT MIN(id) FROM subjects WHERE survey_id = '6be229a0-f497-4d19-a76c-f11361f9573b')
  ORDER BY a.subject_id
                                                       QUERY PLAN                                                        
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Gather Merge  (cost=146543.16..147095.03 rows=4730 width=13)
   Workers Planned: 2
   Params Evaluated: $1, $3
   InitPlan 2 (returns $1)
     ->  Result  (cost=28.26..28.27 rows=1 width=4)
           InitPlan 1 (returns $0)
             ->  Limit  (cost=0.43..28.26 rows=1 width=4)
                   ->  Index Scan Backward using subjects_pkey on subjects  (cost=0.43..112951.62 rows=4059 width=4)
                         Index Cond: (id IS NOT NULL)
                         Filter: ((survey_id)::text = '6be229a0-f497-4d19-a76c-f11361f9573b'::text)
   InitPlan 4 (returns $3)
     ->  Result  (cost=28.26..28.27 rows=1 width=4)
           InitPlan 3 (returns $2)
             ->  Limit  (cost=0.43..28.26 rows=1 width=4)
                   ->  Index Scan using subjects_pkey on subjects subjects_1  (cost=0.43..112951.62 rows=4059 width=4)
                         Index Cond: (id IS NOT NULL)
                         Filter: ((survey_id)::text = '6be229a0-f497-4d19-a76c-f11361f9573b'::text)
   ->  Sort  (cost=145486.60..145492.52 rows=2365 width=13)
         Sort Key: a.subject_id
         ->  Nested Loop  (cost=212.59..145354.07 rows=2365 width=13)
               ->  Parallel Bitmap Heap Scan on subjects s  (cost=212.01..10754.52 rows=1691 width=4)
                     Recheck Cond: ((survey_id)::text = '6be229a0-f497-4d19-a76c-f11361f9573b'::text)
                     ->  Bitmap Index Scan on ix_subjects_survey_id  (cost=0.00..211.00 rows=4059 width=0)
                           Index Cond: ((survey_id)::text = '6be229a0-f497-4d19-a76c-f11361f9573b'::text)
               ->  Index Scan using ix_answers_subject_id on answers a  (cost=0.57..78.65 rows=95 width=13)
                     Index Cond: ((subject_id = s.id) AND (subject_id <= $1) AND (subject_id >= $3))
```

By artificially constraining the `subject_id` range in the `answers` table, suddenly the appropriate indices are used, and the cost of the second query is much, much less than the cost of the first query.

This makes no sense to me. The first query is using a table join on appropriately-indexed fields. Why isn't the join on the first query then using the `subject_id` index on the `answers` table? Why do I have to add these additional lines to make this query fast? Thank you in advance for your help.

EDIT:

I was asked to run an EXPLAIN ANALYZE on the first query. Here are the results.

```
 Gather Merge  (cost=9451079.11..9561465.15 rows=946100 width=13) (actual time=897277.506..898030.532 rows=987075 loops=1)
   Workers Planned: 2
   Workers Launched: 2
   ->  Sort  (cost=9450079.09..9451261.71 rows=473050 width=13) (actual time=897263.631..897454.544 rows=329025 loops=3)
         Sort Key: a.subject_id
         Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 7936kB
         Worker 0:  Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 7928kB
         Worker 1:  Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 7304kB
         ->  Parallel Hash Join  (cost=11073.71..9397405.26 rows=473050 width=13) (actual time=210253.324..896783.279 rows=329025 loops=3)
               Hash Cond: (a.subject_id = s.id)
               ->  Parallel Seq Scan on answers a  (cost=0.00..8708933.87 rows=258055787 width=13) (actual time=0.795..801307.363 rows=206386656 loops=3)
               ->  Parallel Hash  (cost=11051.75..11051.75 rows=1757 width=4) (actual time=26.276..26.277 rows=1320 loops=3)
                     Buckets: 8192  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 256kB
                     ->  Parallel Bitmap Heap Scan on subjects s  (cost=213.24..11051.75 rows=1757 width=4) (actual time=24.771..25.497 rows=1320 loops=3)
                           Recheck Cond: ((survey_id)::text = '6be229a0-f497-4d19-a76c-f11361f9573b'::text)
                           Heap Blocks: exact=25
                           ->  Bitmap Index Scan on ix_subjects_survey_id  (cost=0.00..212.18 rows=4217 width=0) (actual time=26.259..26.259 rows=3959 loops=1)
                                 Index Cond: ((survey_id)::text = '6be229a0-f497-4d19-a76c-f11361f9573b'::text)
 Planning Time: 0.248 ms
 Execution Time: 898333.782 ms
```

Comment: You could try and create a compound index on `subjects(id, survey_id)`, since your query uses both columns.

Comment: You should switch the tables (answers a where subjects s is and vice versa) in the first example.  All rows from table a is probably joined with s as the contraint in where clause is only on table s and that value isn't known until after the join.  In the latter case, you are putting a restraint on table a in the where clause so the optimizer selects only those for the join.

Comment: Bjarni - Unfortunately this did not change anything. 
  EXPLAIN SELECT a.subject_id, a.answer
  FROM wp_fieldwork.subjects s
  INNER JOIN wp_fieldwork.answers a ON s.id = a.subject_id
  WHERE s.survey_id = '6be229a0-f497-4d19-a76c-f11361f9573b'
  ORDER BY a.subject_id

Comment: GMB - Thank you very much. Unfortunately this did not change anything.

Comment: Does the first query ever finish?  If so, please show Please show `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE)` for it, not just EXPLAIN

Comment: A couple other items to consider. How good are your statistics? What is the expected distribution of subject_id across the answers table. This leads the optimizer determining the percentage of data blocks needed to resolve the query. At some percentage it actually becomes much faster to do a sequential scan (especially when done in parallel) as the data can just be streamed whereas an index lookup requires 2 physical I/O for each block. Properly indexed for most queries does not mean properly indexed for all queries.

Comment: jjanes - EXPLAIN ANALYZE on the first query added at your request.

Comment: Belayer - subject_id is mostly sequential across the answers table, but not perfectly so. Should I re-sort the table to make it perfectly sorted by subject_id?

Answer (score 0):

In the first example some 800 million rows from answers are joined with subjects before the where condition can be applied, as it is bound to subjects.
In the second example only answers with the correct subject_is (or very limited subset) need to be joined with subjects as answers is in the where clause.

Best regards,
Bjarni.

Comment: Thank you, Bjami. Why is that though? Why wouldn't the index be used to determine which of the rows from the answers table would get used to join to the subjects table?

Comment: Well.  This would require the optimizer to figure out which table to read first (possibly from more than two tables) with regards to the where clause and the join clause.  Probably not a simple thing to do.  This is just my guess mind you.